# WPF Exception "Root Element is Missing"

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, rss

I have written code in WPF c# to get RSS Atom XML Feed but it gives an Exception that root element id missing. How to solve this can you please help me. My code is:

```
try
{

  string url = @"http://myweblink/newlink.xml";
  string username = "";
  string password = "";

  Uri uri = new Uri(url);
  HttpWebRequest rssFeed = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
  rssFeed.Method = "GET";
  rssFeed.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
  using (DataSet rssData = new DataSet())
  {
    //read the xml from the stream of the web request
    rssData.ReadXml(rssFeed.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

    //loop through the rss items in the dataset 
    //and populate the list of rss feed items
    foreach (DataRow dataRow in rssData.Tables["item"].Rows)
    {
      newlistt.Add(new RssFeedItem
      {
        ChannelId = Convert.ToInt32(dataRow["channel_Id"]),
        Description = Convert.ToString(dataRow["description"]),
        ItemId = Convert.ToInt32(dataRow["item_Id"]),
        LinkURL = Convert.ToString(dataRow["link"]),
        PublishDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dataRow["pubDate"]),
        Title = Convert.ToString(dataRow["title"])
      });
    }
  }    
}

catch (Exception ee)
{
  MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
}
```

Comment: what is in http://myweblink/newlink.xml?

Comment: egads, do not use `DataSet`.  It is very old and should be deprecated.  Take a look at LINQ to XML.

Comment: Have you looked at the root element of the XML? The error indicates it's not properly formed.

Comment: @Amicable Yes i put this link in browser and that works but not in my code:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `DataSet`; it is very old and not intended for general-purpose XML reading.  I recommend using LINQ to XML.  Something like this:

```
var feed = XDocument.Load(rssFeed.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
var ns = feed.Root.Name.Namespace;
var items = (from e in feed.Root.Elements(ns + "item")
             select new RssFeedItem
                        {
                            ChannelId = (int?)e.Element(ns + "channel_Id") ?? -1,
                            Description = (string)e.Element(ns + "description"),
                            // ...
                        }).ToList();
```

Deal with missing values as you see fit.

Comment: How to put this in list @MIKE?

Comment: ah, it's probably an XML namespace issue.  Give me a moment.

Comment: Updated.  Note how `ns` is prepended to the element names to match elements in the same namespace as the root element.

Comment: Mike i write this: `var feed = XDocument.Load(rssFeed.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
var ns = feed.Root.Name.Namespace;
foreach( var e in feed.Root.Elements(ns + "item"))
newlistt.Add(new RssFeedItem{
 ChannelId = (int?)e.Element("channel_Id") ?? -1,
 Description = (string)e.Element("description"), });MessageBox.Show((string)e.Element("description"));}` but it shows MessageBox and nothing in Window

Comment: Does the feed you are reading have those elements?  What URL are you scraping from?  The element names changed in RSS 2.0, so that could be your problem.  Try changing `"item"` to `"entry"` and `"description"` to `"title"`, then pull from http://stackoverflow.com/feeds.

Comment: My answer was intended to show you an alternate method of parsing XML.  Figuring out what all the different feed formats and versions are is a whole other question :).